# How to get Tfs WorkItem AssignedTo email address using IdentityManagementService while having same DisplayName value for multiple WorkItems?

Tags: c#, tfs

Hi I'm using the following code to get Email addresses of collection of WorkItem's AssignedTo field.My problem here is there are so many WorkItems that contain same DisplayName value for their AssignedTo filed value.That's why i'm getting the error

"Multiple identities found matching 'xxxxxx'. Please specify one of the following identities"

Please suggest me how to get rid of this error.

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection projCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
    IIdentityManagementService ims = projCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
    WorkItemStore WIS = (WorkItemStore)projCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
    WorkItemCollection WIC = WIS.Query(workItemQuery);      
    foreach (WorkItem wi in WIC)
    {                
        var workItemIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,(wi.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].OriginalValue).ToString(), MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you catch "MultipleIdentitiesFoundException" exception , the variable gives you an option to select the unique identity.

```
catch(MultipleIdentitiesFoundException ex){var workItemIdentity = ex.MatchingIdentities[0].UniqueName;}
```

This is just a workaround. its little difficult which one would be valid identity at that moment. But this generally happens if the same use has email address in two different domains.
Hope it helps.